# Finding area of a location on a google map plotted in R by connecting points (lon-lat)

Tags: r, google-maps, plot, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to calculate area of a marked location with points and lines using ggmap and ggplot2 libraries. I am not finding any example of how to calculate areas by connecting points of longitudes and latitudes in R.

My code for the points and lines of the location for which I am working to find area is below:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

coordinates <- read.csv("U://30-Power & Water//25 Renewables//R plots//plant location plot//lat_lon.csv", header=T)

coordinates <- data.frame(coordinates) 

map <- get_map(location = c(mean(coordinates[1:13,3]), mean(coordinates[1:13,2])), zoom = 13, maptype = "satellite", source = "google")

Sweihan <- ggmap(map)+
  geom_point(data = coordinates, aes(x = coordinates[,3], y = coordinates[,2]))+
  geom_path(data = coordinates, aes(x = coordinates[,3], y = coordinates[,2]))
+ geom_polygon(data = coordinates, aes(x = coordinates[1:13,3], y = coordinates[1:13,2])) 

Sweihan
```

My data looks like this :

```
     Point Latitute..N. Longitude..
1     P1     24.53450    55.41547
2     P2     24.52929    55.41913
3     P3     24.52929    55.43241
4     P4     24.54342    55.46566
5     P5     24.55113    55.46241
6     P6     24.55545    55.47364
7     P7     24.56041    55.47109
8     P8     24.55841    55.46529
9     P9     24.55867    55.46521
10   P10     24.54863    55.43838
11   P11     24.54712    55.43917
12   P12     24.54085    55.42715
13   P13     24.54043    55.42712
14    P1     24.53450    55.41547
```

please help me finding approach for calculating area that I can use within my code so that when I plot points of lat and lon on the map, I get the exact area that  these points cover.

Any type of your help will be appreciated!

Comment: If you do not mind using the leaflet package, you can achieve the task with `addMeasure()`. You may want to have a look of the function, if necessary.

Comment: @ jazzurro, can you please elaborate that approach a bit. Will appreciate it! I'll search for it too..

Comment: OK. Let me prepare something for you. One sec.

Comment: This is a sample from the manual. `leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>% fitBounds(-73.9, 40.75, -73.95, 40.8) %>% addMeasure()`. Play with the code and see what happens. Basically, you can drop points by hand. Once you finish that, you can see the size of the area you created.

Comment: @jazzurro Thanks a lot! Actually I can do this and I am definitely going to give it a try but I have a lot work already done using ggmap and ggplot libraries. If there's any method that I can use with these libraries, it would be very helpfull!

Comment: Is your data (lat/lon points) static or does it change? If it's static, you can create a spatial object from your points and calculate the area directly on them using `library(sf)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a matrix of lon/lat coordinates

```
p <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20))
library(geosphere)
areaPolygon(p)

# with your data "d"
# areaPolygon(as.matrix(d[,3:2]))
```

Or for a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

```
library(raster)
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
a <- area(p)
```

Comment: @ RobertH thanks a lot! I haven't started working with shape files but you first code helped. and I have verified the area of my location using the approach @Calum explained above.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more generic approach to find the area of a polygon described by a set of coordinates. This uses the active simplefeatures standard for spatial data provided by the package `sf`. The steps go as follows:

1. Read in the points to a table with `read_table2()`
2. Select only the coordinate columns and convert to a matrix with `as.matrix()`
3. Wrap inside a list with `list()`. This is necessary to convert the coordinates into a geometry object.
4. Use `st_polygon` to turn the points into a polygon
5. Use `st_sfc` and `st_set_crs` to give the package an understanding that the polygon coordinates are in a latitude/longitude system (4326 is a code that corresponds to the extremely common WGS84 standard for coordinate data)
6. Use `st_area` to calculate the area of the polygon.

The code for this is a straightforward pipe:

```
library(sf)

tbl <- readr::read_table2(
  "Point Latitude Longitude
  P1     24.53450    55.41547
  P2     24.52929    55.41913
  P3     24.52929    55.43241
  P4     24.54342    55.46566
  P5     24.55113    55.46241
  P6     24.55545    55.47364
  P7     24.56041    55.47109
  P8     24.55841    55.46529
  P9     24.55867    55.46521
  P10     24.54863    55.43838
  P11     24.54712    55.43917
  P12     24.54085    55.42715
  P13     24.54043    55.42712
  P1     24.53450    55.41547"
) 

tbl[, c(3,2)] %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  list() %>%
  st_polygon() %>%
  st_sfc() %>% 
  st_set_crs(4326) %>% 
  st_area()
7919415 m^2
```

Comment: nice answer. For this example loading the whole of the `tidyverse` is not required, as you're just using `readr::read_table2()`.

Comment: And I think `sf` requires the column order to be lon/lat, rather than lat/lon

Comment: Oops, will fix that one!

Comment: @Calum thanls a lot for this explanation! it helped a lot!